# How to write a sum loop with a criteria in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run a loop that checks if cells in column A is not empty then it will take the integer in column B in the same row and sum it to the previous integer, when the cell in column A is empty then it will print the sum in the next row in column B.

```vb
X = 0

For myCounter = myRow To 1 Step -1
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(myCounter + 1, 1).Value)
    X = Cells (myCounter,10).Value + X
Loop
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk3Mb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    'Set you sheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Start from row 2
        For i = 2 To LastRow

            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then

                .Range("B" & i - 1).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value + .Range("B" & i - 1).Value

            Else

                .Range("B" & i + 1).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't do exactly what I need. it substitutes the previous value with the value of the cell that it stands on and at the end it doesn't print the sum of all the range that it runs on. How to fix it that it will sum the B column and print the sum and won't substitute the values in the cells?

Comment: It s better to upload an images with the data and one with the desirable outcome.

Comment: i added a picture